# how to conditionally pass a node to a template in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I know how to pass a node to a template.
However, I don't find how to pass a node to that template using conditions without rewriting the same `xsl:call-template` statements, like so:

```xml
<xsl:call-template name="processNode">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$isConditionTrue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$nodeA"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nodeB"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:with-param>   
</xsl:call-template>
```

The problem with this is that I don't get the node in my template, but the text value (because I use `value-of`), so I lose all it's attributes and other elements.

I know that following solution will work:

```xml
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$isConditionTrue">
        <xsl:call-template name="processNode">
            <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="$nodeA"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="processNode">
            <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="$nodeB"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But given that my real template has much more params than this simplified example, I wonder if it is possible using a conditional structure inside the `xsl:with-param` statement when you call the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather abstract example, and there may be another way to look at the real situation. Within the given framework, you could use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="processNode">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="$nodeA[$isConditionTrue] | $nodeB[not($isConditionTrue)]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Of course, in XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of` within the `xsl:choose` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the current version of XSLT is XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 as its expression language; since XPath 2.0 you could simply use e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="if ($isConditionTrue) then $nodeA else $nodeB"/>`.

In XSLT 1 I would use e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="pNode" select="($nodeA[$isConditionTrue]|$nodeB)[1]"/>`.

And of course `value-of` is always the wrong tool to copy node structures, you would need to use `copy-of`, whether inside of `with-param` or elsewhere; `value-of` creates a text node.